# Group data by DATE and sort by DATETIME mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection `events` in mongodb. I want to `GROUP` data on basis of DATE (d-m-Y) only from `event_time` field but after that `sort` on basis of `datetime (d-m-Y H:i:s)`

My Collection sample and solution i tried is [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7wuHM3WCQd1)

For now, When i run query, everytime i get `products` array unsorted/shuffled, but i want to get  `products` array sorted by `DATETIME (d-m-Y H:i:s)` but outer result will be sorted by `date (d-m-Y)`

**PS: I also use UNWIND stage before SORT stage in production to use SKIP and LIMIT stage.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of problem is `$addToSet` in `$group` stage, it will not preserve order, you can try another approach,

- `$sort` by `event_time` in descending order
- `$group` by `event_time` date and push all `product_id`s
- `$reduce` to remove all duplicate `products`, check if product not found then concat initial value of reduce
- `$sort` by `_id` means date in descending order

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "cuid": "608707",
      "event_name": "product_viewed"
    }
  },
  { $sort: { event_time: -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": {
        "$dateToString": {
          "format": "%d-%m-%Y",
          "date": "$event_time"
        }
      },
      "products": { "$push": "$event_data.product_id" }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      products: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$products",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $cond: [
              { $in: ["$$this", "$$value"] },
              "$$value",
              { $concatArrays: ["$$value", ["$$this"]] }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { _id: -1 } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MqHX2lPEa-R)

Comment: Just for information (as separate case), As $addToSet insert elemnt in Array, Is there any way we insert a DOCUMENT in array... like `[{product_id : 123 , datetime : SOME_VALUE}, {product_id : 345 , datetime : SOME_VALUE}]`

Comment: there is other way is `$push` operator. that we have used in query.

Comment: will you please show me an example of inserting DOCUMENT into array please... (example using any dataset ,just for knowledge).

Comment: you mean in $group stage right? see the [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/un35JVcsyPK)